# Extract multiple lines based on certain regex assertion condition

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have a large text file and I need to extract certain blocks of data based on particular conditions found in the following lines from the beginning. How can I find those blocks and extract them using Python regex package?

The sample file (source.txt) is shown below.

```
    .
    .
    .
    Request: 22:11:22
    Discription1: From the Client 1
    Discription2: requesting HTTP
    Version: 1.2
    Type: browsing
    Data: AAAA CFFFF FFF

    Answer: 33:22:44
    Discription1: From Server B
    Discription2: Respons HHTP
    Version: 1.1
    Type: browsing
    Data: kCmkc9AS 9as9 as99 as76d 8aS9d8 6ASDQWv sf

    Request: 31:24:53:33
    Discription1: From Client 2
       Discription2: requesting HTTP
        Version: 1.1

    Type: DASH
    Data: AAAA CFFFF FFF



    Answer: 41:24:33:33
    Discription1: From Server A
    Discription2: Response
    Version: 1.1
    Type: DASH
    Data:ask sef k5q3 WEB 54 fkl n5 qwe@#%@#SDG adkjwra;k4 kfk

    Request: 61:44:23:33
    Discription1: From Client 2
        Discription2: requesting HTTP

    Version: 1.1
       Type: DASH

    Data: AAAA CFFFF FFF
    Data Discription: From the Cleint VM2
    Answer: 71:25:33:33
      Discription1: From Server A
     Discription2: Response
        Version: 1.1
    Type: DASH

    Data:ask sef k5q3 WEB 54 fkl n5 qwe@#%@#SDG adkjwra;k4 kfk
    .
    .
```

I need to get the blocks that start with "Request: " with features: "version 1.1" and "Client 2"

---

### Important notes

1. The length of the blocks varies, so they don't have the same
   information, yet they have the same matching features.
2. They have many spaces and newlines in between.
3. The matching features may not come exactly in the specific line
   order.
4. I need to capture those blocks up to the following "Answer" Keyword.**

---

The expected output is:

```
 Request: 31:24:53:33
    Discription1: From Client 2
    Discription2: requesting HTTP
    Version: 1.1
    Type: DASH
    Data: AAAA CFFFF FFF

    Request: 61:44:23:33
    Discription1: From Client 2
    Discription2: requesting HTTP
    Version: 1.1
    Type: DASH
    Data: AAAA CFFFF FFF
    Data Discription: From the Cleint VM2
```

Comment: You need to be more clear than this. Give an example scenario.

Comment: That question is now deleted (10k+ users can see it, but they will not be able to comment or answer).

Comment: I have updated this one.

Answer (score 0):

You might make use of negative lookaheads to assert the values on the next line:

```
^Message Request: .*(?:\r?\n(?!.* Client 2|Data:).*)*\r?\n.*Client 2.*(?:\r?\n(?!Version: 1\.1).*)*\r?\nVersion: 1\.1(?:\n(?!Data:).*)*\r?\nData: .*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of line
- `Message Request: .*` Match Message Request: and the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n(?!.* Client 2|Data:).*)*` Match as long as the line does not contain Client 2 or starts with Data:
- `\r?\n.*Client 2.*` Match the line with Client 2
- `(?:\r?\n(?!Version: 1\.1).*)*` Match as long as the lines does not contain Version 1.1
- `\r?\nVersion: 1\.1` Match the line that contains Version 1.1
- `(?:\n(?!Data:).*)*` Match as long as the line does not start with Data:
- `\r?\nData: .*` Match the line that starts with Data:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SF6qy7/1)

For example using `re.M`

```
import re
regex = r"^Message Request: .*(?:\r?\n(?!.* Client 2|Data:).*)*\r?\n.*Client 2.*(?:\r?\n(?!Version: 1\.1).*)*\r?\nVersion: 1\.1(?:\n(?!Data:).*)*\r?\nData: .*"

with open("source.txt", "r") as f:
    text1 = f.read()
print (re.findall(regex,text1, re.M))
```

Result

```
['Message Request: 31:24:53:33\nDiscription1: From Client 2\nDiscription2: requesting HTTP\nVersion: 1.1\nType: DASH\nData: AAAA CFFFF FFF', 'Message Request: 61:44:23:33\nDescription0:jdfj sdjd\nDiscription1: From Client 2\nDiscription2: requesting HTTP\nVersion: 1.1\nType: DASH\nData: AAAA CFFFF FFF']
```

Comment: Can I doent use the negative assert? This is because I have many version types. Also, can I don't use serarch from the start with ^, in calse this comes not in the first of the line.

Comment: I will be highly regarded if you could simplify the pattern since it is quite advanced and need to be broken up, at least for me as a beginner.

Comment: You can omit the `^` if you want, but then the match can also start at another place. You mention `version 1.1` in the question so I assume that shoul be specified in the pattern. The negative lookahead only makes sure that the line does not contain that value. What do you mean by different types? Where can they occur?

Comment: Can I consider the end of the block is "Message Answer: " not the Data? This is because the fields may vary in the requested blocks, but the only stable ones are the conditions.

Comment: suppose, for example, you have other versions, e.g. 1.2, 1.0

Comment: Sure, like this? https://regex101.com/r/JFaqpz/1 Do you want to match versions that start with `1.` and then up to 9? Then is could be like https://regex101.com/r/JFaqpz/2

Comment: Also, can we amend the code if the lines have many spaces? since I've noticed that I cannot get the complete blocks if there are some spaces in. I have just updated the text file.

Comment: This will now match 0+ whitespace chars after version, where version can be 1.0, 1.1 etc https://regex101.com/r/JFaqpz/3

Comment: What I want is to match exactly on the given fields, e.g. the version should be 1.1 and the client should be Client 2. Technically, I have certain matching fields but several information lines in the blocks that can be different from block to other with different spaces and newlines between

Comment: That is difficult to test without extended data examples. This would match version 1.1, trailing whitespaces and matches until the next occurrence of Message Answer. https://regex101.com/r/JFaqpz/4/

Comment: Can you please, go through the text file again? This is the final version that I want to match against it.

Comment: Can we have another simplified solution that does not have negative lookahead? What I want exactly is to say: Bring the blocks up to the "Message Answer" That include version 1.1 and Client 2. Take into consideration the spaces and newlines.

Comment: When I aggregate this solution with mine, it does not give me the exact outcome. Suppose we have just "Request:" instead of "Message Request:" and "Answer:" instead of "Message Answer:" , as shown in the updated question code, how could we extract the blocks?

Comment: If you want to match both, you could make Message optional https://regex101.com/r/2N42Vi/3

Comment: I require to extract the blocks with the same conditions mentioned previously, version 1.1 and Client 2. The last solution gives me all the possibilities (4 blocks). Can you please maintain it?

Comment: You keep adjusting the requirements. Try https://regex101.com/r/ied9Qt/1 If this pattern works I will update my answer as it does not reflect initial example data anymore. If the requirements change again, I would suggest asking a new question and specify exactly what should and should not be matched.